# Vertical-align:top not working on table when printing

Tags: html, css

This is my first post here, so if you need some more information just tell me.

I have a table which is working fine in browsers, but when i print the text is aligned to the middle, ignoring my "vertical-align: top" setting.

When i inspect the print style in chrome, it seems like it's ignoring the vertical align I've set. The only place it's written in there is in "user agent stylesheet", where it's set to "inherit". The "user agent stylesheet" is from what I've understood the browsers settings?

I've set the vertical-align in both my regular stylesheet and my print stylesheet, but nothing is working. It's starting to get a tiny bit annoying. I've also tried setting valign on the table, with the same result.

The table is built like a normal table, like this:

```
<table valign="top">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your media query declaration. However, if you use html tables why not use the property instead of the CSS?

You are declaring that `<td>` and `<th>` elements will be `display: table-cell` and this is inneccessary because is the default style. I think you should use this:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td valign="middle">
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Setting it in the table gives me the same result. Also, it is in the middle now when printing, but I need it to be in the top.
The rest of the print css is working, so I don't think the media queries is the problem.

Comment: If you write `valign="top"` the result is the same? Maybe you need to check if you have a reset or something like this. Are you trying with `!important` in your css? With the code you've shared is impossible to know more.